# laravel @error underfined variable message

Tags: php, laravel, message

I have a form, where I try to make validation:

```
@extends('html')

@section('title', 'create')
@section('content')

    <h1>Create service</h1>
    <form action='/service' method='post'>
        <input type='text' name='name'>
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <button>Add service</button>
    </form>
    @error('name') {{ $message }} @enderror

@endsection
```

There is a function processing request:

```
public function store(Request $request){
        $data = $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required'
        ]);
        $var = request('name');
        DB::table('services')->insert(['name' => $var]);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

When I try to open a page with a form I get such error:

```
    ErrorException Undefined variable: message
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which version of laravel are you using?

Comment: i am using laravel 6 and Openserver

Comment: Can you show me route for these files

Comment: Route::post('/service', 'ServiceController@store');

Comment: Probably you are not using web middleware

Answer (score 1):

try by giving this class in input

```
<input type='text' name='name' class="@error('name') is-invalid @enderror">
```

or you can use this also

```
@if ($errors->any())
 <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
 </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your $message is undefined.

Maybe try this:

```
 <input type="email" name="{{$name}}" id="input-{{$name}}" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="{{ __($label) }}" value="{{ old($name) }}" required autofocus>


  @if ($errors->has($name))
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first($name) }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
```

In this snippet i check if there is a error and if there is a error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```php
@extends('html')

@section('title', 'create')
@section('content')

    <h1>Create service</h1>
    <form action='/service' method='post'>
        <input type='text' name='name'>
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <button>Add service</button>
    </form>
    @error('name') {{ $errors->first('name') }} @enderror

@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional statement in blade file or putt `@` symbol before a variable name. 
see the below example. this will definitely solve your problem

```
 @error('name') {{ $message ?? '' }} @enderror

/// OR

 @error('name') {{ @$message }} @enderror
```